# I'm trying to use hashcat to crack a password that I forgot, but I get a weird error

Tags: opencl

While running my hashcat command :

```
./hashcat -m 7100 -a 3 -o cracked.txt /Users/{user}/Downloads/mainhash.txt "?d?d?d?s?d?u?u?u"
```

I get the following error:

```
clBuildProgram(): CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

<program source>:7:10: fatal error: 'inc_vendor.h' file not found
#include "inc_vendor.h"
^

* Device #1: Kernel /usr/local/Cellar/hashcat/6.2.5/share/hashcat/OpenCL/shared.cl build failed.
```

```
clCompileProgram(): CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

<program source>:7:10: fatal error: '/Users/{user}/Desktop/hashcat/OpenCL/inc_vendor.h' file not found
#include M2S(INCLUDE_PATH/inc_vendor.h)
^
<built-in>:34:16: note: expanded from macro 'M2S'
#define M2S(x) XM2S(x)
^
<built-in>:37:17: note: expanded from macro 'XM2S'
#define XM2S(x) #x
^
<scratch space>:2:1: note: expanded from macro '#'
"/Users/{user}/Desktop/hashcat/OpenCL/inc_vendor.h"
^

* Device #2: Kernel /Users/{user}/Desktop/hashcat/OpenCL/shared.cl build failed.
```

Please help

Comment: `'inc_vendor.h' file not found` is a clear indication there's a missing file named inc_vendor.h.

Comment: I know, but what is that file, I have no idea what that is or what is does...

Comment: https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2270

Comment: I looked inside the issue, but can't really find a proper answer or solution